# Find the number of positive integers $n$ such that $\big(n + 2n^2 + 3n^3 + ... + 2005n^{2005}\big)$ is divisible by $(n-1)$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, problem-solving

> Find the number of positive integers $n$ such that $\big(n + 2n^2 + 3n^3 + ... + 2005n^{2005}\big)$ is divisible by $(n-1)$.

**What I Tried**: I can write the expression as :-
$$\rightarrow n\big(1 + 2n + 3n^2 + ... + 2005n^{2004}\big)$$

We know $(n-1)$ cannot divide $n$, so it must divide that expression. That was only useful I was able to conclude. I am not finding any other ideas on how to tackle this problem using mod, I might put some small values for $n$ but I cannot continue like that, it will take ages.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you take that expression mod $n-1$, what do you get? That should work out reasonably quickly.

Comment: How will you take mod of such a big expression?

Comment: Termwise is often a good approach.

Comment: Oh, completely forgot about that, I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed.)

**Hint:**

$$n + 2n^2 + 3n^3 + ... + 2005n^{2005} \equiv 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + 2005 \pmod{n-1} . $$

**Corollary:** We need $ n-1 \mid \frac{2005 \times 2006 }{ 2 } $. How many factors does this number have?

Comment: Got it, your hint just made me solve the problem. The number will have $16$ factors and answer will be $16$ as well.